# Did I do this Laplace transform correctly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> 1) $w'' + w = t^2 + 2$; $w(0) = 1$, $w'(0) = -1$
>
> 2) $s^2W(s) - sw(0) - w'(0) = \frac{2 + 2s^2}{s^3}$
>
> 3) $s^5W(s) - s^4w(0) - s^3w'(0) = 2 + 2s^2$
>
> 4) $ W(s) = \frac{2 + 2s^2 - s^3 + s^4}{s^5}$
>
> 5) $W(s) = 2\left(\frac{1}{s^5}\right) + 2\left(\frac{1}{s^3}\right) - \frac{1}{s^2} + \frac{1}{s}$
>
> 6) $w(t) = \frac{2}{4!}t^4 + t^2 - t + 1$

Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is a defect in your solution. In fact, we have: $$s^2W(s)+1-s+W(s) = 2/s^3+2/s$$ instead which leads us to have: $$W(s)=\frac{2+2s^2-s^3+s^4}{s^3(s^2+1)}$$

Comment: Incorrect. This is because the RHS is equivalent to $\frac{2+2s^2}{s^3}$.

Comment: @DonLarynx: B.S. has the correct form for $W(s)$ and your answer is incorrect. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti: That doesn't answer my question. Regards

Comment: Question: Did I do Laplace correctly? Answer: No. I am confused. What B.S. shows is what you should have for $W(s)$ and your $w(t)$ is wrong. Am I not making this clear enough for you?

Comment: @Amzoti: You should not be participating in this discussion. Give me a dispute why my work is wrong. I will even award you a 50+ bounty in two days.

Comment: @Amzoti: keep in mind Laplace Transforms are NOT unique

Comment: Keep in mind that you are wrong and it is not even close! Perhaps before you throw a tirade, you should actually understand what you are doing. Look at your step 2 for your problem! Wow!

Comment: You made me laugh. I shall award you a +50 bounty in 2 days. (Remind me.)

Comment: I am just confused on this: So I really have $s^2W(s) - s + 1 = \frac{2+2s^2}{s^3}$. Now I get $s^5W(s) - s^4 + s^3 = 2+2s^2$. But then $W(s) = \frac{2 + 2s^2 + s^4 - s^3}{s^5}$.

Comment: Never mind. I am fool.